# using node-fluent-ffmpeg to transcode with ffmpeg on windows not working

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm trying to use the module node-fluent-ffmpeg (https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) to transcode and stream a videofile. Since I'm on a Windows machine, I first downloaded FFMpeg from the official site (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Then I extracted the files in the folder C:/FFmpeg and added the path to the system path (to the bin folder to be precise). I checked if FFmpeg worked by typing in the command prompt: ffmpeg -version. And it gave a successful response.

After that I went ahead and copied/altered the following code from the module (https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/master/examples/express-stream.js):

```
app.get('/video/:filename', function(req, res) {
res.contentType('avi');
console.log('Setting up stream')

var stream = 'c:/temp/' + req.params.filename
var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: configfileResults.moviepath + req.params.filename, nolog: true, timeout: 120, })
    .usingPreset('divx')
    .withAspect('4:3')
    .withSize('640x480')
    .writeToStream(res, function(retcode, error){
        if (!error){
            console.log('file has been converted succesfully',retcode);
        }else{
            console.log('file conversion error',error);
        }
    });
});
```

I've properly setup the client with flowplayer and tried to get it running but 
nothing happens. I checked the console and it said:

```
file conversion error timeout
```

After that I increased the timeout but somehow, It only starts when I reload the page. But of course immediately stops because of the page reload. Do I need to make a separate node server just for the transcoding of files? Or is there some sort of event I need to trigger?

I'm probably missing something simple but I can't seem to get it to work. 
Hopefully someone can point out what I've missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by using videoJs instead of Flowplayer. The way flowplayer was launched did not work properly in my case. So I init the stream and then initialize videojs to show the stream. Which works great.